# What's the explicit difference when looking at Differential Equations vs Stochastic Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, stochastic-calculus

I learned differential equations from mathematics text and have having some trouble with its application in statistics. Specifically applied to stochastic time series.

From my time series text reads "The general solution to a differential equation is defined to be a particular solution plus all homogenous solutions."

$\ y_{t}=Aa^{t}_{1}+\dfrac {a_{0}}{\left( 1-a_{1}\right) }+\sum ^{\infty }_{i=0}a^{i}_{1}\varepsilon _{t-1} $

I'm familiar with the first two expressions of the equation. If homogenous is taken to be the same as the complementary solution -- my understanding is there's a "complementary function". This function never had a random disturbance parameter. So with this added I was hoping there could be a simple explanation without needing the derivation.

The notion of 'all homogenous equations' is also lacking some understanding.

Original Equation:
**$\ y_{t}=a_{0}+a_{1}y_{t-1}+\varepsilon _{t} $**

$\ y_{t}=a_{0}\sum ^{t-1}_{i=0}a_{i}i+a^{t}_{1}y_{0}+\sum ^{t-1}_{i=0}a^{i}_{i}\varepsilon _{t-i} $

$\ y_{t}=a_{0}\sum ^{t-1}_{i=0}a^{i}_{1}+a^{t}_{1}\left( a_{0}+a_{1}y+\varepsilon _{0}\right) +\sum ^{t-1}_{i=0}a^{i}_{1}\varepsilon _{t-i} $

$\ y_{t}=a_{0}\sum ^{t+m}_{i=0}a^{i}_{1}+\sum ^{t}_{i=0}a^{i}_{1}\varepsilon _{t-i}+a^{t+m+1}_{1}y _{-m-1} $

$\ y_{t}=\dfrac {a_{0}}{1-a_{1}}+\sum ^{\infty }_{i=0}a^{i}_{1}\varepsilon _{t-i}$

With the assumption of unknown initial conditions the first term in the equation reduces to the Aa1 term.

Comment: Could you please add the differential equation that leads to your given solution? What I see is more a difference equation or a recursion equation $$y_{t}=a_1y_{t-1}+a_0+ε_t$$ which in repeated insertion gives \begin{align}
y_t&=a_1(a_1y_{t-2}+a_0+ε_{t-1})+a_0+ε_t\\
&=a_1^2(a_1y_{t-3}+a_0+ε_{t-2})+(a_1+1)a_0+a_1ε_{t-1}+ε_t\\
&=\dots\\
&=a_1^ky_{t-k}+\frac{1-a_1^k}{1-a_1}a_0+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_1^jε_{t-j}\\&=a_1^t(a_1^Ny_{-N})+\frac{1-a_1^{N+t}}{1-a_1}a_0+\sum_{j=0}^{N+t-1}a_1^jε_{t-j}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes you're correct now that I've looked at some of its derivations. It's successive iteration to generalize the solution. I posted the original equation above. Having looked at it though it seems as simple as that and nothing complex going on? The objective function includes the error term, and it's iterated forward from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the usual argument for any linear equation, if $y_t$ and $z_t$ are two different solutions, then by subtracting the recursion equations you get
$$
(y_t-z_t)=a_1(y_{t-1}-z_{t-1})
$$
which means that the difference of the two inhomogeneous solutions is a homogeneous solution. In the other way, any sum of inhomogeneous solution and homogeneous solution is again an inhomogeneous solution.

If $L$ is a linear operator, then $L(y)=b$ and $L(z)=b$ implies $L(y-z)=0$, and if $L(v)=0$ then $L(y+v)=L(y)+L(v)=b+0$.

---

In your case with a stochastic perturbation you have to care especially for convergence if you go the way I did in the comment. However, you can come from the side of the desired result and define $e_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_1^j ε_{t−j}$ which can be proven to converge almost everywhere so that $e_t=a_1e_{t-1}+ε_t$ and in the difference of these equations
$$
(y_t-e_t)=a_0+a_1(y_{t-1}-e_{t-1})
$$
you get a classical recursion equation $x_t=a_0+a_1x_{t-1}$ without any stochastic terms. As this has the known solution $x_t=Ca_1^t+\frac{a_0}{1-a_1}$ one can reconstruct the solution from this.

Comment: I follow the reasoning and math. When recursively iterating 'back to period 0' from the original differential. The texts remarks leading to the same general solution, as to when iterating recursively forward. Such that:

Comment: $\ y_{t}=a_{0}+a_{1}\left[ a_{0}+a_{1}y_{t-2}+\varepsilon _{t-1}\right] +\varepsilon _{t} $

Comment: $\ =a_{0}\left( 1+a_{1}\right) +a_{1}\varepsilon _{t-1}+\varepsilon _{t}+a^{2}_{1}\left[ a_{0}+a_{1}y_{t-3}+\varepsilon _{t-2}\right]  $

Comment: How is period t defined? I understand and follow completely. But this notion of 'iterating back' and 'forward' to t and back to period 0 is strange. If yt is taken as the initial equation, how would you get to period 0 with the sequence? This feels like some simple calculus that I'll have to jog memory on.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I described in taking the limit $N\to\infty$. I replaced that by the short-cut of the ad-hoc definition of $e_t$ which follows the pattern of the $ε$ sums of the insertions. There is no real connection between the finite and infinite sums, therefore one has to restart the solution process but now can define $x_t=y_t-e_t$ following a deterministic recursion.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a ton. 
If I can ask a last question. I came acrros the expression along the derivations including:

$$ y_t=b_0+a_0t+ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \epsilon_{t-i} $$

It then states that this is an improper solution because the sum of the {e} sequence may not be finite. Therefore it requires imposing the initial conditions by including the initial $ y_0 $ conditions.

What exactly is it referring to? I'm confused by 'finite' sum when its a sum to infinite. Is it referring to expectation?

Comment: The value of the series may not converge, in fact it is infinite with probability $1$ if the $ϵ_t$ are normally distributed.